# If statement is not working

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, pdo

I have 2 sql queries in my code where the second one is wrapped around an if statement which should only execute if a certain post value exists.

But I still get the following error message:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a
>   child row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (`database1`.`table2`,
>   CONSTRAINT `fk_referals_users1`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`) REFERENCES
>   `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON
>   UPDATE NO ACTION)

Clearly that if statement is not working, if it was, it would not get to the second sql query.

Here is the problem section of the script:

```
$STH = $DBH -> prepare( "insert into database1.table1 (display_name, email, password) values ( :display_name, :email, :password )" );

$STH -> bindParam( ':display_name', $_POST['display_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100 );
$STH -> bindParam( ':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100 );
$STH -> bindParam( ':password', $_POST['password'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100 );

$STH -> execute();

if( isset( $_POST['referer'] ) or ( $_POST['referer'] != null ) or ( $_POST['referer'] != "" ) ) {
    $STH = $DBH -> prepare( "insert into database1.table2 ( username, status, users_id ) values ( :username, :status, :users_id )" );

    $strStatus = 1;

    $STH -> bindParam( ':username', $_POST['display_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100 );
    $STH -> bindParam( ':status', $strStatus, PDO::PARAM_INT, 1 );
    $STH -> bindParam( ':users_id', $_POST['referer'], PDO::PARAM_INT, 1 );

    $STH -> execute();
}
```

Comment: Also, you could make your IF condition by just checking for empty `if (!empty($_POST['referer'])) {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IF statement checks whether a certain POST value is set. Your foreign key constraint checks whether the value in the POST field is present in the `users` table. These two conditions are not related. The POST field can be set with a value that is not present in the `users` table. You should check whether the value is present in the users table (do a COUNT maybe?) before trying to insert (this depends on your setup, of course)

Also, you should use `empty()` for your IF condition as `isset()` will trip your condition to TRUE even if the value is empty. Better to use

```
if (!empty($_POST['referer'])) {
   //your code here
}
```

Comment: Yes, but because the $_POST value is empty, it should not be reaching that second query.

Comment: if $_POST is empty but set, your condition will trigger to TRUE because isset() returns true. You should use `if (!empty($_POST['referer'])) {}` instead.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks.  Please update your answer with this so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

One of your if conditions is resolving to true.

**Break your compound if statement into 3 nested ifs and add an echo at each level to see which one(s) are failing**.

Answer (score 1):

`null` and `""` are different values, so if it equals `null` it will not equal `""` and the IF will pass true.  I recommend this `if ( $_POST['referer'] && strlen($_POST['referer']) > 0 )`.  This will check if it is null or not (if it is not set it is null) and if there is a string with a length greater than 0